# Django, Python Loop Logic Problem

Tags: python, django-models

This works, partially.  More information may be needed, however, I thought I would post to get advice on anything obvious that might be wrong here.

The problem is that if activity.get_cost() returns a `False` value, the function seems to exit entirely, returning `None`.

What I'd like it to do, of course, is accumulate `cost` Decimal values in the `costs = []` and return their sum.  Simple, I would have thought... but my novice Python skills are apparently missing something.

More information provided on request.  Thank you.

```
def get_jobrecord_cost(self):
    costs = []
    for activity in self.activity_set.all():
        cost = activity.get_cost()
        if cost:
            costs.append(cost)
    if len(costs):
        return sum(costs)
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_jobrecord_cost(self):
    return sum((activity.get_cost() or 0 for activity in activity_set.all()) or 0)
```

Depending on how much data you're dealing with, this version is just a bit more efficient than DNS's because it uses a generator comprehension and doesn't require loading up a whole list into memory.  It's functionally equivalent to grieve's except the looping happens in C.  Note that this doesn't necessarily mean this is *better*.  This approach is obviously more dense and can be less readable.

Answer (score 3):

I notice you're returning False if all the costs were None; I don't know if there's a specific reason for that, but it does make it a little bit harder to write.  If that's not a requirement, you could write it like this:

```
def get_jobrecord_cost(self):
    costs = [activity.get_cost() or 0 for activity in self.activity_set.all()]
    return sum(costs)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can simplify this with:

```
def get_jobrecord_cost(self):
    costs = 0
    for activity in self.activity_set.all():
        cost = activity.get_cost()
        if cost:
            costs += cost

    return costs
```